# 5GHZ Band transmission range is extremely short

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I recently got a new [NETGEAR WNDR4300](http://support.netgear.com/product/WNDR4300).

It is dual band, 2.4GHz and 5GHz. The 2.4GHz band works fine, but the 5GHz band's transmission power is *incredibly* short. I'd say you can stand up to 3 feet away from the router before you lose connection.

Like I said, 2.4GHz transmits perfectly fine.

This is my setup:

### 2.4GHz

[image]

---

### 5GHz

[image]

Comment: 5ghz can transmit several dozen feet its not the frequency that's the problem but the radio the problem is your routers quality is low

Comment: @Ramhound Equally likely that the wireless chip in the laptop/phone doesn't work very well on that band. Either way, one meter is definitely far from normal and does indicate a problem. Perhaps try turning off the 2.4 GHz radio, or changing the channel, or checking for signal quality (and crowding) with something like inSSIDer, or reducing the max speed ("Mode").

Comment: It does it with multiple things.

Comment: A custom firmware might allow you to increase the power to the radio but that likely will increase the chance the device is unstable

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities spring to mind:

1. You're on a channel with lots of intereference. Try a different channel, and not 161, since it's part of the same 40MHz pair with 157.
2. You've got a loose or damaged antenna or bad  (faulty/damaged) 5GHz radio on one device or the other. Try a different 5GHz AP or a different 5GHz client. If that helps, check with your vendor if still under warranty, otherwise open it up and look for a disconnected or damaged antenna lead.

Update: One last tip: When it comes to interference in 5GHz, besides "other 5GHz Wi-Fi networks in the area", the usual suspects include 5.8GHz cordless phones, "rooftop wireless" ISPs that often use 5.8GHz signals, and things-that-use-5GHz-Wi-Fi-but-don't-tell-that, like the Wii U's use of 5GHz Wi-Fi Direct/Miracast as the link between the gamepad and the set top box.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed in the diagram, the region setting is being set as "North America", which would only allow the transmission of 50 mW at the max. 50 mW is OK for 2.4 Ghz transmission but too weak for the 5 GHz radio. If the device allow you to change the region setting, change it to country/region like "TW", that would allow higher output.

Comment: The region selection is greyed out and I can't right-click it to change its readonly value.

Comment: [It would also highly likely put you in violation of applicable regulations.](http://superuser.com/a/640086/53590) While the 5 GHz WiFi band is unlicensed, that does not mean it is *unregulated*.

Comment: You're thinking of the "UNII-1", or "low" band (ch 36 - 48). But look at his channel. He's using channel 157 in the upper band where FCC allows 1W ( == 1,000 mW == 30 dBm).