# How do I change my router's region?

Tags: router

I asked a question about my 5GHz range being extremely short on my [NETGEAR WNDR4300 Router](http://support.netgear.com/product/WNDR4300).

I got [this](https://superuser.com/a/639773/147220) answer, basically telling me to change the region my router is located.

However, the region option is greyed out:

[image]

---

I am unable to right-click it, and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and following the path gives this, causing me to believe it's just iframing a website (based on the iFrame tags):

[image]

---

I am able to change the value here:

[image]

However the box does not update. I want to change it to "TW" per the answer's suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**That answer is likely misguided;** you'd probably be in violation of some FCC regulation if you make such a change and don't watch what you are doing *very* carefully. That may be why the option is grayed out.

Also, **increasing transmit power won't get you very far**, literally and figuratively, unless you go for really large increases. Keep in mind that the received signal strength (or more accurately the field strength) drops with the square of the distance, so if 50 mW *were* to get you only about a meter of coverage radius, to double the coverage radius (to two meters radius) you'd need to increase power fourfold to 200 mW. Four meters would need 800 mW output and eight meters, which is when it starts getting interesting at all, would take somewhere between 3 and 3.5 W of RF output, *approximately 60-70 times the original 50 mW* and almost certainly out of the hardware's specs. (That's ignoring the effects of attenuation through walls and other obstacles for simplicity; in practice, you'd probably need yet more power.) Of course, you'd also need to make the equivalent change on the client device as well, because otherwise while it might be able to pick up the stronger signal it won't be able to communicate back to the router.

[As Spiff said in the higher-voted answer to your previous question](https://superuser.com/a/639776/53590), you really should **look into why you have such dismal radio performance on 5 GHz** before you start doing things which are quite possibly illegal (the 5 GHz WiFi band is unlicensed, but that doesn't mean you can transmit however you like; unlicensed does not equal unregulated) and almost certainly way out of spec of the hardware. First thing to try, borrow another 5 GHz capable router or AP and client device from someone or somewhere and try connecting between those two instead (with the router or AP located where yours is currently located). If you get reasonable coverage then, that means that the problem is with either of your pieces of equipment and not with the 5 GHz WiFi band in your location per se.

Comment: I doubt that the FCC will come around to my house randomly to see how far I'm transmitting. However, the information about how much I need to increase it is helpful, thank you.

Comment: If a licensed radio user (such as the possible wireless ISP mentioned in Spiff's answer) starts seeing interference and it's traced back to your location, somebody is likely to become unhappy.