# What would be the most cost-effective way to connect keyboard to each touch device (IPad, Galaxy Pad, even IPhone)

Tags: keyboard, iphone, bluetooth, ipad, galaxy-s3

I'm working in a QA team and we are testing a website. We are supporting all touch devices and smartphones.

My question: is there an easy solution so that we could write to those devices from your PC's (some specific URL's sometimes need to be imputed, which takes a lot of typing).

I've tried:
1. Sending the links through emails and opening them;
2. Looking at some applications (like http://wifimouse.necta.us/).

Is there a better way? Bluetooth, Wifi keyboards? Or some other.

Comment: The solution would be based on the devices.  In most cases a bluetooth keyboard should work ( ipad for instance ) others that soluton won't work.  The solution also likely will be platform dependent.  I suggest you ask on android.stackexchange.com and http://apple.stackexchange.com/ with specific questions towards the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The great majority, if not all, of Apple and Android mobile devices will pair with a Bluetooth keyboard.  A PC will do this as well if it has a Bluetooth adapter installed.

I've never heard of a Wifi keyboard.

I've had no problems using the Apple Bluetooth keyboard on any Android device, or my PC, other than that shift+space on the keyboard doesn't output a space (ANNOYING IF YOU ARE TYPING LIKE THIS which may not be a bad thing...)

However, you may look into using QR codes for URLs which wouldn't require any typing at all.

Comment: *"I've never heard of a Wifi keyboard."* made me think of [the note on things-that-use-WiFi-but-don't-tell in this answer](http://superuser.com/a/639776/53590). Not saying such a thing exists or not, just a little reference for completeness' sake.